# Bundling & Minification generate source map

Tags: c#, bundling-and-minification, source-maps, asp.net-mvc-5.2, asp.net-bundling

I'm trying to find out if there is a mechanism in ASP.NET's Bundling & Minification that would generate a source map when you are doing on the fly minification of `SCSS`.

I can't find any reference to something like that being available, but I wanted to double check before I looked for another solution.